# Renaming param created by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have a button that let's me create additional input field with every button press, which on submitting form saves every input field into one (array) parameter.

Button erb looks like this:

```
<%= button_tag 'Add a new field', id: 'add_correct_answer', type: 'button' %>
```

While JavaScript behind it looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // When the add_button is pressed
    $('#add_correct_answer').click(function() {
    // Container (already created)
    var container = $('.buttons-fields');

    // Create the input wrapper (input tag + delete button), and append it to `container`
    var input_wrapper = $('<div>', { class: 'input-wrapper' }).appendTo(container);

    // Create an input tag, and append it to input_wrapper
    var input = $('<input>', { name: 'correct_answers[]', type: 'text' }).appendTo(input_wrapper);

    // Create the remove button, append it to input_wrapper, and add a click callback to
    // remove the input wrapper if it's pressed.
    var remove = $('<span>', { text: 'x' }).appendTo(input_wrapper).click(function() {
      input_wrapper.remove();
    });
    });
```

This function creates param that can be called with `params[:correct_answers]` and it equals to array with input fields content.

What I want to do is change that param to `params[:task][:correct_answers]`. How do I do that?

I've tried to change:

```
var input = $('<input>', { name: 'task[correct_answers[]]', type: 'text' }).appendTo(input_wrapper);
```

And it looks fine as parameter, but nothing is being saved into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2d array instead of a 1d array.

1d array is like `int[] a = [23,45,494,599]` Then you call with `a[0]` or whatever as I am sure you know.

However the 2d array is a bit harder. The setup looks something like so:

```
int[] a = 
[
    [1,4,155,164,23,43],//This one
    [8,75,45,3134,45,6],
    [143,55,7,8,8754,5],
]
```

and called with `a[0][3]` and would return 164. The first bracket choses the array inside the big array that I marked "This one" then the second number bracket thing gets the number inside that array.

Now that the explanation of the 2d array is done the real answer:

So 2 ideas. Try using the setup of `task[][]` and doing something like `for(blah)task[I]=correct_answers;` You may not need the for but idk what you really need. Or you can try doing `task[0][0]=correct_answers` but that one I have no idea if it would work. I think I could however so I kept it.

As OP said in the comments:
"
The thing is: I need to change params name. Parameters are not typical variables, so things like you mentioned above would be considered really bad practice. What could actually work, would be assigning params[:correct_answers] to params[:task][:correct_answers] and then deleting params[:correct_answers] before submitting form."

So my way won't work I guess. Unless you don't care about bad practices >:)

Comment: Wait a minute please. Hit post on accident before finished

Comment: The thing is: I need to change params name. Parameters are not typical variables, so things like you mentioned above would be considered really bad practice. What could actually work, would be assigning `params[:correct_answers]` to `params[:task][:correct_answers]` and then deleting `params[:correct_answers]` before submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was change

```
var input = $('<input>', { name: 'correct_answers[]', type: 'text' }).appendTo(input_wrapper);
```

into:

```
var input = $('<input>', { name: 'task[correct_answers][]', type: 'text' }).appendTo(input_wrapper);
```